# appfabric caching failure exceptions=getandlock requests for session state

Tags: asp.net, session-state, performancecounter, appfabric-cache

I'm using the session provider in an asp.net app with a 3 host appfabric cluster.
The cluster is version 3 and is running on windows server 2008.
My sessions cluster has secondaries set to 1 and min secondaries set to 0.

When I look at the cache statistics I notice a very large (disproportionate) number in the miss count category.  In fact it almost equals the request count category.  So with this I decided to look at the performance counters to figure out why the session provider does not seem to be able to hold the object correctly or why it keeps missing.

What I found was that the getandlocks/sec are identical to the failure exceptions/sec counters.  It's also constantly running which is not normal considering that there is only so much traffic being generated by our staff.  The object count is not large but the rejection rate is clearly much higher than the number of objects that should be coming out of it.  I'm not writing or modify that much info to the session, for the most part it doesn't change but clearly I'm getting a significantly larger number of requests than my users can create.

Any help is welcome.

PS.
Ideally I'd love to know what these failure exceptions say but there is no way to capture them it seems.

Comment: Cluster version 3? As far as I know there are two released versions of AppFabric Cache, 1.0 and 1.1.

Comment: Is high availability enabled or disabled?

Comment: version 3 and HA is enabled.  secondaries is 1 and min seondaries is 0, it's a 3 node cluster.

Comment: Where did you obtain the installation from? Do you have a URL? (still confused by what you mean by version 3).